# Match function of Excel with different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I want to use match function but the lookup array is in a different sheet.

Here is what I am trying:

```
= MATCH( "Lead-POI-BBA Concours", SHEET_13_15!F5 : SHEET_13_15!O5)
```

but it is giving an error

```
#N/A
```

I tried changing it to

```
= MATCH( "Lead-POI-BBA Concours", 'SHEET_13_15'!F5 : 'SHEET_13_15'!O5)
```

But it again reverts back to

```
= MATCH( "Lead-POI-BBA Concours", SHEET_13_15!F5 : SHEET_13_15!O5)
```

giving the same error

```
#N/A
```

Where am I making a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need to refer the sheet twice. Its Sheet!Range

```
= MATCH( "Lead-POI-BBA Concours", SHEET_13_15!F5:O5)
```

Comment: If no match found then also its same error. Read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: Thank you, is there a method to avoid #N/A,  in case of unsuccessful match?

Comment: How dare you ask another question before, accepting this as an answer / upvoting it. Just Kidding!! :) Use `IFError` or `IsError`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611.But as a advise avoid asking additional questions in comments.